# Using re.compile to extract file with most recent date

Tags: python, regex

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to extract the most recent file from a folder using Python 3.6.

I'm struggling to match the file name using re.compile. How do I identify the most recent file from a list of files to import it into python? I'd also like to extract the date from the file name.

An example of the file names is 'VAL-FTS_Opals_20180706.xls'

My code is below:

```
import os

# Import pandas
import pandas as pd
#Import re & datetime for date identification & handling
import re
import datetime


# Retrieve current working directory (`cwd`)
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd
# Change directory 
os.chdir('E:\Python\Portfolio Data')

# List all files and directories in current directory
filelist = os.listdir('.')


#Extract date string from the filenames
date_pattern = re.compile(r'\d{8}')

def get_date(filename):
    matched = date_pattern.search(filename)
    if not matched:
        return None
    m, d, y = map(int, matched.groups())
    return datetime.date(y, m, d)

dates = (get_date(fn) for fn in filelist)
dates = (d for d in dates if d is not None)
#Find the last date
last_date = max(dates)
```

Comment: I don't know why you have **date_pattern, it should just be date_pattern and you also have an unclosed string on that line. For most recent file try something like `max(fillelist, key=get_date)`

Comment: If you have those kinds of perfectly formatted (for date comparision) filenames you don't need to start with RegEx at all. You could just use filename[-12:-4] to get the datestring and sort for that.

Comment: If all the file names are of the form `VAL-FTS_Opals_YYYYMMDD.xls`, won't the first element in the sorted(descending) list of files be the recent file?

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Using `datetime.datetime.strptime`

**Ex:**

```
date_pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<date>\d{8})')

def get_date(filename):
    matched = date_pattern.search(filename)
    if not matched:
        return None
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(matched.groups('date')[0], "%Y%m%d")

dates = (get_date(fn) for fn in filelists)
dates = (d for d in dates if d is not None)

last_date = max(dates)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Rakesh. That's great.